# Prevent MPI from busy looping

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi, busy-waiting, intel-mpi

I have an MPI program which oversubscribes/overcommits its processors. That is: there are many more processes than processors.

Only a few of these processes are active at a given time, though, so there shouldn't be contention for computational resources.

But, much like the flock of seagulls from *Finding Nemo*, when those processes are waiting for communication they're all busy-looping, asking "Mine? Mine? Mine?"

[image: Nemo Seagulls]

I am using both Intel MPI and OpenMPI (for different machines). How can I convince them **both** not to busy loop?

My quick and dirty solution has been to use `MPI_Iprobe` in a loop with a sleep command (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37062120/752843)).

Comment: Are you running all processes on a single host?

Comment: No, they may be distributed across a number of hosts.

Comment: What kind of network connects the hosts?

Comment: I actually have that issue on a single host, just haven't had the chance to do my own research on it. Thus I would be really interested if there was a general answer, not just for a particular BTL.

Comment: @Zulan, I don't believe there is a general switch for that. Each BTL has its own synchronisation and notification needs and preferences based on the hardware beneath.

Comment: @HristoIliev: it would be ideal of the answer were not dependent on the particulars of the network. In one scenario I am using everything is on the same host. In another there are multiple hosts.

Comment: As something of a product plug, you could look at using [Adaptive MPI](http://charm.cs.illinois.edu/manuals/html/ampi/manual.html) to oversubscribe MPI ranks without oversubscribing processes, and hence not having a busy-wait condition. As a bonus, it can load-balance the active ranks among processes (and hence processors).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a been a while since this has been asked but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560714/probe-seems-to-consume-the-cpu) may have the answer you're looking for. (tl;dr pass `--mca mpi_yield_when_idle 1` as a parameter to `mpirun` if you're using OpenMPI)

Other than that, if your MPI processes are waiting at MPI Barriers, you can set the I_MPI_WAIT_MODE=1 to prevent the busy loop in INTEL's MPI. for OpenMPI, see linked post.